# with sqlplus how to spool data into csv where column contains newline

Tags: newline, sqlplus, spool

With sqlplus how to spool data into csv from table where some column contains newline?

resulting row in csv should be in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the linefeeds by usage of the function replace:

```
select colA,colb, ... REPLACE(colX, chr(10),'\n'), ...
```

Thus the line feeds will be replaced by \n. You could also delete them this way or change the content of the table before creating the CSV.

Clumsy, but the best sqlplus offers.